# Using an enum on one side of a many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel

If I have an enum for `role` and I have a table of `suppliers`, how can I allow a `supplier` to have multiple `roles`?

I have considered a `hasMany` relationship from `supplier` to a `supplier_role` table, but the `supplier_role` table is then just full of repeated enums in each row:

```
id | role     | supplier_id
1  | producer | 1
2  | producer | 2
3  | producer | 3
4  | producer | 4
5  | producer | 5
6  | reseller | 1
```

I've considered removing the `enum` and going for a traditional pivot, with another table defining the roles. For example, the tables would look like:

`supplier` | `supplier_role` | `role`

Then instead of the enum, each enum value would be a row in the `role` table. Then linked via a `manyToMany`.

But ideally, I want to keep the enum, it's used elsewhere in the application. What is the standard approach here (maintaining the use of the enum)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put a class between the enum and the relation.
For example :

- Entity/Role
- Entity/Supplier
- Enum/RoleEnum

Supplier is linked to the Role entity.
The role Entity have a string as "name" but a RoleEnum in constructor (and the getName() returns a string but you can also return a RoleEnum object).

The "enum" entity:

```
// Entity\Role

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: RoleRepository::class)]
class Role
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private string $name;

    public function __construct(RoleEnum $role)
    {
        $this->name = $role->value;
    }

    public function getId(): Uuid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNameEnum(): RoleEnum
    {
        return RoleEnum::from($this->name);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The enum itself:

```
// Enum\RoleEnum

enum RoleEnum: string
{
    case PRODUCER = 'producer';
    case RESELLER = 'reseller';
}
```

You can therefore do a ManyToMany relation between Role and Supplier with your ORM but guarantee that Role is in RoleEnum.

```
// Entity\Supplier

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SupplierRepository::class)]
class Supplier
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Role::class, inversedBy: 'suppliers')]
    private Collection $roles;

    ...
}
```

The ORM will create the role_supplier table by itself. If you dont work with an ORM it's the same, you just have to create it yourself.